# Spring Boot - Cannot read application.yml values from instantiated object

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to read some setting values from application.yml using the @ConfigurationProperties annotation.

An instantiated object of the class `TestClass` uses the properties class, so I added the `@Configurable` annotation, but the `properties` always be `null` and it causes NullpointerException.

The properties class:

```java
@ConfigurationProperties
@Getter
@Setter
public class Properties {
    
    private String setting;

}
```

And the object which uses the properties:

```java
@Configurable
public class TestClass{

    @Autowired
    private Properties properties;

    void print(){
        System.out.println(properties.getSetting());
    }
}
```

If I call the print method, `NullPointerException` will be occurred:

```java
TestClass testClass = new TestClass();
testClass.print();
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: `@Configurable` has always been fragile and unreliable. It's much better to use constructor parameters instead.

Comment: Have you enabled AspectJ (e.g. as described at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-bean-into-unmanaged-objects)?

Comment: @dunni Thanks, I tried setting that but have the same issue...

Comment: @Daigo what is the reason that you have `@Configurable` ? Do you need AOP AspectJ ?

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos Not really, I just thought it is needed to read the application.yml from an instantiated object. `TestClass` needs to be instantiated since it has parameterized constructor. I’m new to using this so my thought could be completely wrong.

Comment: @Daigo check updated answer

Comment: Thank you for your kind support, I got to understand the meaning of each annotation! I still have the problem but will try to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer:**

Find the class that is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` and add there also the annotation `@EnableConfigurationProperties(Properties.class)`

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(Properties.class)
public class ServiceLauncher {
```

**Explanation:**

`@ConfigurationProperties` does not register the class that brings this annotation as a spring bean. It is only used so that Spring can read the properties with some meta configured information (ex `prefix = "some.prop.prefix"`).

If you wish to use this class as a spring bean (ex via `@Autowired`) you need to combine the above annotation with `@EnableConfigurationProperties` which then says to spring that this class must become a spring bean.

**Another workaround:**

You could also instead just use the `@Component` on the Properties class and that would be enough without the need of `@EnableConfigurationProperties` but the later is better practice to be used.

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties
@Getter
@Setter
public class Properties {
```

**Edit:** After clarrified in the comments there is also another mistake in this  code. You should replace `@Configurable` with `@Configuration`. The first one does not create a spring bean on the class that is placed!

Comment: Thank you, I've tried both, but got the same result. The properties can be referred from another location so I believe the bean setting is incorrect...